# How to create a (configurable) number of temporary download links

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a download link that works only 10 times.So I got 2 options.

- Downloading a file and updating its count to database and delete file
  when count is 10.
- Or downloading a file and renaming to filename-1 ,
  filename-2.......filename-10 .. and finally delete it when it reaches
  filename-10.

I guess second option use less resource for not calling database.Now What is the   easy way to find the file name.For example:

All my filenames are unique like **sadkjsah78876djhgsadj.jpg**.So when i update count it will be like

```
sadkjsah78876djhgsadj-1.jpg
(or)
sadkjsah78876djhgsadj-8.jpg
```

So how to find the file name based on sadkjsah78876djhgsadj in a directory.I am thinking of looping .but I dont think thats the best method when i set download limit to 100.

Comment: I would DEFINITELY go with the database option. It's better on so many levels.

Comment: but there are millions of download files will be generated..and also i must create cron jobs to delete those lists..

Comment: Updating millions of rows in a database is quite a lot better than dynamically renaming millions of files though. That's what databases are for. If you set it up properly, there won't be a load problem.

Comment: ohh alright , I willl use database than :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option is to use an `.htaccess` with `mod_rewite` to rewrite calls to a certain directory to a PHP file. e.g. any calls to `/downloads/FILEHASH.jpg` get rewritten as `/download.php?file=FILEHASH`

The `download.php` would then check if the `FILEHASH` matches a row in the DB and that the dl count was under `x`, if so, it would increment the dl count, set the response code as `200`, content-type to `image/jpeg` and fire out the image data (either as stored in the filesystem or from a BLOB in the DB).

If not found or if the the dl count was over `x`, it would set the response code as `404` (or something more appropriate if you prefer) and either return nothing or maybe a helpful message. Depending on volume of files, you should probably also delete the row from the DB and unlink the file from the filesystem at this point.

If you use an MVC framework, this kind of thing is really straightforward.

If you're serving up more than just images, make sure you get the upload's mime type when it's being added, save that in the DB and serve that as the content-type when downloading.